# CUDA arrays and c++ vectors

Tags: arrays, vector, cuda

I'm new at CUDA and have the following question? My kernel is supposed to calculate a type:

```
vector <double *> *my_vector = new vector <double *>();
```

Before I tried to change the original c++ code to cuda it would calculate an array[6] in a loop and then push it back to my_vector.

```
for{
          //calculations


        double *array = new double[6];
        array[0] = data;
        array[1] = data;
        array[2] = data;
        array[3] = data;
        array[4] = data;
        array[5] = data;

        my_vector->push_back(array);
}
```

I know that using thrust could help but I prefer if I didn't use it. I thought of using a 2D array at my kernel and copying the data back to my host code and then copying that to my_vector with the std::vector. What I've tried so far has failed.

If anyone has some experience on this and has any idea it would be much help.

Comment: There is no STL support in CUDA, and `malloc` support in kernels is *very* slow. You might want to think about another approach.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [the Thrust](http://thrust.github.io/) template library that provide useful templates for host and device code usage. The `thrust::device_vector` can be used like `std::vector` analogy, although not inside device code.